# Calculate Age using DOB in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get the DOB of a person via a JSON Object (Shown below). All what I need to do is to calculate a persons age. The approach I took is given below, However, I always get NaN as the output. Can someone help me solve this ?

```
{
  "dob":"2020-05-07"
}
```

CODE

```
Age (dob :string) : string {
    var ag = Date.now() - new Date(dob).getTime();
    var ad = new Date(ag); 
    return Math.abs(ad.getUTCFullYear() - 1970).toString();
  }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: Feel free to make use of the Edit button provided by SO if you think there's an error in the way I have presented the post. I am new to Angular and other JS frameworks, I have limited knowledge of knowing what's right and wrong.

Comment: Well, put it another way: does the code you've posted refer to any types or interfaces defined by Angular? This isn't even specific to _TypeScript_, as you're not asking about types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several methods of creating a new date in JS.

```
let today = new Date()
let birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')
let birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
let birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17)            // the month is 0-indexed
let birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0)
let birthday = new Date(628021800000)
```

But you are passing a string which doesn't match any of the above format. So you can split the string and use the day, month and year separately. Also make sure to subtract 1 from month as it starts from 0 and ends at 11 in the JS world.

```
Age (dob :string) : string {
    let [year, month, day] = dob.split('-');
    month -=1;
    const ag = Date.now() - new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
    const ad = new Date(ag); 
    return Math.abs(ad.getUTCFullYear() - 1970).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have update your Age function please test it.
You are passing wrong value to new Date ()

```
Age (dob :string) : string {
    var ag = Date.now() - new Date(dob.split("-")).getTime();
    var ad = new Date(ag); 
    return Math.abs(ad.getUTCFullYear() - 1970).toString();
}
```

Comment: But can you pass `dob.split("-")` into the `new Date()` ? I get the error `No overload matches this call.`